# Installing Oracle Calendar on Fedora

Tags: fedora

Im trying to install oracle calendar on fedora and Im running into the following problem

```
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
awk: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dirname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
basename: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dirname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
basename: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
hostname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Launching installer...
grep: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/tmp/install.dir.7150/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the LD_ASSUME_KERNEL environment var can cause problems, it is old var used during the time of kernel threading switch. Some apps, mostly java, still have this set and it cuases problems in fedora. The soluction is to turn it off:

```
perl -pi -e 's/export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL/#xport LD_ASSUME_KERNEL/' cal_linux
```